# VB.net regex exclude certain characters from string

Tags: vb.net

I am using regex.ismatch to check a string doesn't contain any one of a list of characters such as £&+(/?!;:* And also a quotation mark " not sure how to place that...

But can't get to to work...

```
If Regex.ismatch(Line, "^[^@#£&+()*']"). Then
    Msgbox("error")
End If
```

But doesn't work for me?

Any suggestions

Comment: It looks like you want `Not Regex.IsMatch(Line, "[@#£&+()*'""]")`. Use two double-quotes in a string in VB.NET to represent a single double-quote. Or maybe without `Not`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily without Regex by simply doing something like this:

```
Public Shared Function HasSpecialChars(ByVal str As String) As Boolean
    Const specialChars As String = "!@#$%^&*()"
    Dim indexOf As Integer = str.IndexOfAny(specialChars.ToCharArray())
    Return indexOf <> -1
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like that too, I dont see the quotation mark tho?   for e.g.  

Dim ch As String = ")(*&%$!" 'etc.. 
For x = 0 th ch.Length-1
         If myStr.Contains(ch(x)) Then Error
Next x

Comment: You modify the specialChars string to include the characters you want to search for